# how to configurate ssh-keygen on codeanywhere?

Tags: ssh-keys

How can I connect to the SSH of my Container (Linux and OSX)?

1. open your terminal
2. type in ssh-keygen and you will create your public key
3. go to .ssh/id_rsa.pub and copy your entire key
4. In Codeanywhere, in Container's SSH, use command: cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub
5. use command vim authorized_keys
6. (type "A" or "I") paste your key in new line and Save (by pressing ESC, and entering :wq)
7. Locate SSH port number in Container's Info
8. Now in order to connect to your box, you have to use the following command to create a tunnel from your local machine to your Container: `ssh -P port cabox@hostXX.codeanyhost.com -i id_rsa.pub`

I can't really understand what they are given starting from step 4. Please explain about this in a easy way.

Comment: You may want to clarify what Codeanywhere is (Some kind of VM container running a variant of Linux ?) - maybe provide a link of some sort.

Comment: i can't understand

Comment: CodeAnywhere seems to be quite a small project, and Instructions 4-8 are used in Unix and are fairly straight forward commands to do with accessing a unix box. Its difficult for people who would otherwise be able to advise you to do so to help without more context - but basically all they are doing is advising how to set up a public-private key system for SSH.

Comment: yeah but now what should i do

Comment: No offense, but I think you are way out of your depth.  You may want to find someone local who has some Linux server skills to help you understand the basics.   If you are a Windows person, instead of following the instructions you laid out, you might have an easier time by following the instructions on setting up Putty at http://docs.codeanywhere.com/other/faq.html